# HTML 5 GeoLocation in Google Chrome

Tags: html

I am using HTML 5 Geolocations API's for tracking location however I am getting the following error on the Geolocation icon in Chrome Browser

> "This Page has been blocked from tracking your Location"

I went to the Preferences and Setting's Page but did not find any help.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that I opened the HTML file from the file system (`file:///...`). Browsers generally try to prevent accessing personal information (which includes location) from local files, so you have to serve the file through a web server (even if it is local).

One simple way to serve a static website located in your filesystem is `SimpleHTTPServer` if you have Python installed. Just navigate to the folder using the command prompt, and say `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`, and then you can view the file on `localhost:8000`.

Answer (score 0):

Even I was facing the same problem. One of the solution is to open to file in another browser, I tried in Firefox and it worked fine. Another solution is to open the file through your WAMP server (Local host).

Answer (score -1):

There is a good article [here](http://thoughtresults.com/geolocation-api) about Geolocation API. You have to go to chrome://settings/content and there, you can find Location information. You should be able to find the exceptions and manage them there.

Comment: This is not a helpful URL.